# Move app submission from a directory to another

Tags: microsoft-teams, office-store

I have an old Microsoft/Live account where I have submitted an app for Microsoft Teams. That account and directory is no longer in use, as we use our primary organization directory for app submissions now. So I would like to move the app submission from the old directory to another, and need tech support for that. I have tried all channels inside the Microsoft Partner Dashboard without luck.

Comment: Customer Service questions are off topic here. Please open a Customer Support ticket instead by signing to Marketplace Publisher Support at https://aka.ms/marketplacepublishersupport

Comment: Yes, I assumed that. But after creating my fifth ticket in several channels in the Microsoft support regime, the last Microsoft support personnel I talked to insisted that I created a "ticket" here. I explained that it is an open forum and there will be no ticket but a question, but she advised me to post here because docs.microsoft.com directs to here.

I have tried creating ticket in the Partner Portal twice now, but I always end up wrong place and being redirected to another support team and a new round of explaining it all over again. Microsoft Support from a technical angle is not easy.

Answer (score 0):

This is called "reparenting" in the Microsoft store lingo, and it is a very very very (very) frustrating process (at least my experience was). They also seem to change whether they're allowing it or not, over time, so you might need to raise several service requests. I hope the process goes smoothly for you.

Comment: I noticed. Been tossed back and forth since February. Frustrating, but one day I will talk to the right technical guy that fix this in 2 minutes :-) Keeping my fingers crossed.

Comment: try connect with me on LinkedIn